# How to change sidebar navbar color in SBAdmin2 bootstrap theme?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I tried typing it inline but couldn't find it and typed it but couldn't find.

background-color:red; color:red  dont work.

SBAdmin2 theme => https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMndz.png

Comment: `sidebar { background:red !important;}` to change background red color.

Comment: red, blue, green are the options already given to us. Does not accept any other hex code colors like #fffff

Comment: Hi #fffff hex code having 6 letter or 3 **#ffffff** or **#fff**.

Comment: Hex (6 letters = `#ffffff`) or 3 (`#fff`) letters colors not accepted. It only accepts certain colors, **blue, green** etc. How can I change it with the color I want?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBPfW.png check here i added background:#111; changed sidebar color to black.

Comment: Thnx.Understood. so what is the name of this color coding? I want to change the hex color to this 3 letter code.

Comment: it is short of hex code [that is](https://encycolorpedia.com/111111)

Comment: You are welcome to StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

On class tag `<ul>`, you can change `bg-gradient-primary` to `bg-gradient-danger`
[change background color sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUtpT.png)